# xml editor - xml plumbing tool

Tags: xml, editor, notepad++, converters, xml-editor

I am looking for a simple xml "plumbing tool" - some sort of notepad capable of doing simple xml transformation jobs using XPath queries or scripts, etc

By "simple transformation jobs" I mean - take the input xml, and delete all nodes which satisfy xpath query.

Or take the input xml and append a small chunk of xml as a first child to of all nodes which do satisfy another xpath condition.

Ideally it should be a free tool, but would not mind paying for a good tool though.

Any recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using oXygen for a while and I'm very happy with it probably the best xml editor(but not free (: ).

Comment: +1 likewise. oXygen is good, and very customizeable. Alternatively, vi is always a +